# custom shell script as a build step in order to define which task to run first

Tags: android, bash, gradle

In my Android studio project.
I want to have custom shell script as a build step in order to define which task to run first.

```
task printHello(type: Exec) {

    workingDir "$rootProject.projectDir/"

    //on linux
    commandLine './hello.sh'
}
```

And following is hello.sh :

```
#!/bin/bash
# declare STRING variable
STRING="Hello World"
#print variable on a screen
echo $STRING
```

I also wonder if I can execute Gradle tasks using bash script?

**Addenda**

```
./gradlew task1
./gradlew task2
```

Can I use following in .sh file?

Comment: ./gradlew yourTaskName ?

Comment: What if I want to execute them one after other? I added a sample to my question in Addenda section...

Comment: then you should create such tasks as task1Task2 and set order in groovy

Comment: Could you please show me how?

Comment: @orium, you can share it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can set order in command line
./gradlew task1 task2
or
./gradlew task2 task1

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work as expected, but when I used them sequentially as I specified in Addenda section, it worked as expected. Thanks for sharing idea->+1